# Teclado mobile não abre em site bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap, mobile

Fiz um site responsivo com bootstrap, porém ao clicar sobre os inputs o teclado do celular não é acionado. O que pode ser?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class='col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2'>
    <div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable' style="text-align:center">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> Este sistema está rodando em fase de teste! Qualquer erro favor entrar em contato pelo e-mail: desenvolvimento@webmeta.com.br
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

        <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" align="center">
            <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a" width="80%">
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form role="form" method="post" action="checar_dados.php?enviar=checar">
              <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Login" name="login" type="text" autofocus required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" name="senha" type="password" value="" required>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Lembrar senha
                                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Login">
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
  <script src="dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Coloque o código na sua pergunta

Comment: Me parece funcionar bem. Você está fazendo o teste usando seu navegador ou o site já está no ar?

Comment: Site está no ar já

Comment: Tem como passar o link. Vai facilitar achar o problema

Comment: www.suportemeta.com.br

Comment: Dando uma olhada no seu site parece que você está com problemas no jquary. Adicione o jquary mais atual e carregue ele antes de qualquer script

Comment: Uma boa prática é vc colocar todos os seus scripts abaixo do último elemento do seu body, sem esquecer de colocar o código do jquary primeiro

Comment: Ok, vou tentar aqui. Valeu!